# Javascript Canvas: Drawing over picture

Tags: javascript

I have been having a problem with a drawing on a canvas. I want the user to be able to change the background on the canvas and I will eventually want to be able to type something in an input box and it will appear on the canvas in boxes. I have been trying to get more on the screen after they have choosen a background (which works fine), but when I try to add just a simple box I can't. I have been trying to do it in different parts of the code but doesn't work for me, and haven't been able to find a solution.

So what I am asking, is there a specific way you have to do it in order to have 
a image (choosen with a select tag, which I already have working), and be able to draw a box ontop of the image choosen. Hope someone can explain to me how I will be able to do so!

```
function load(){
  draw()
}

//Canvas change background
function draw(){
  changeBackground("assets/images/1.jpg");
}


function changeBackground(imagePath){
  var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
  var img=new Image();
  img.onload = function(){
        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,954,507);
  };
  img.src=imagePath;
}


function background(){
  var imageN = document.getElementById("imageselector").value;
  console.log("Image picked as a Background: " + imageN)
  changeBackground("assets/images/" + imageN + ".jpg");
}
```

Comment: Hi! Have you looked at FabricJs already? This might help you with what you are trying to achieve: http://fabricjs.com/

Comment: @AlgefAlmocera No I have not. But I have been trying to avoid using a library since I want to try it with just what I have :)

Comment: You can play around with this example: https://jsfiddle.net/unx4eto2/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to delay the text and boxes and then it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

Let this be a good foundation for your app!

Happy coding!

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
const imageInput = document.querySelector("#imageInput");
const textInput = document.querySelector("#textInput");
const imageUrl = 'https://i.picsum.photos/id/944/600/600.jpg';

imageInput.value = imageUrl;
const state = {
  image: null,
  text: ''
}

const width = window.innerWidth;
const height = window.innerHeight;;
canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;

textInput.addEventListener("keydown", ({key}) => {
  const value = textInput.value;
  
  if(key === "Backspace") {
    state.text = value.substring(0, value.length - 1);
  }
  else {
    state.text = value + key;
  }
  
  render();
})

imageInput.addEventListener("input", () => {
  getImage(imageInput.value)
    .then(image => {
      state.image = image;
      render();
    })
})

const render = () => {
  clear();
  drawBackground(state.image);
  drawText(state.text);
}

const drawText = (text) => {
  context.font = "40px Comic Sans";
  context.fillStyle = "white";
  const textMeasure = context.measureText(text);
  context.fillText(text, width / 2 - textMeasure.width / 2, height / 5);
}

const clear = () => {
  context.fillStyle = "white";
  context.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
}

const getImage = (imagePath) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const image = new Image();
  
  image.onload = function() {
    resolve(image);
  };
  
  image.src = imagePath;
})

const drawBackground = (image) => { 
  context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height);
}

getImage(imageInput.value)
  .then(image => {
    state.image = image;
    render();
  })
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
  background: white;
}

#textInput, #imageInput {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
}


#canvas {
  position: absolute;
  z-Index: -1;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<div id="box">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <input id="imageInput" type="text" placeholder="Enter src or dataUri of an image...">
    <div>
      <input id="textInput" type="text" placeholder="Enter text to show up...">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```